# Find transactions by memo

Tags: transactions

I would like to sum up all transactions values with memo = "abc". Is it possible to filtering transactions by memo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What service are you using? Your best bet would be to write a script yourself using [Cleos](https://eosio-nodeos.readme.io/docs/cleos-overview). 
If you aren't a programmer and want to do it manually, you can use `https://www.bloks.io/account/<your_account_name>`
Just go to the "Token transfers" tab:[image]

 Unfortunately, I don't yet know of any EOS mainnet block explorers that allow CSV downloads.